# Как получить данные из input?

Tags: javascript

Привет! 
Есть код:

```
<div class="input-inner">
    <form>
        <input type="date" class="firstDate" name="firstDate">
        <input type="date" class="secondDate" name="secondDate">
    </form>
</div>
```

Как с помощью JS принимать данные на ходу? Т.е. без нажатия button
Проверять на правильность заполнения даты в полях и сравнения этих двух дат?

```
    var firstDate = document.getElementsByClassName("firstDate")[0].value;
    var secondDate = document.getElementsByClassName("secondDate")[0].value;

    function formatDate(date) {

        var dd = date.getDate();
        if (dd < 10) dd = '0' + dd;

        var mm = date.getMonth() + 1;
        if (mm < 10) mm = '0' + mm;

        var yy = date.getFullYear() % 100;
        if (yy < 10) yy = '0' + yy;

        return dd + '.' + mm + '.' + yy;
    }

    var d = new Date(2014, 0, 30);
```

Вот есть такой код, но что делать с ним дальше, ума не приложу, на jquery сделал бы это, но вот надо на чистом JS
Как совершить проверку этих данных с помощью функции formatDate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
    function onDateChange(obj)
    {
    console.log(obj.name,obj.value);
    }
```

```html
    <div class="input-inner">
        <form>
            <input onchange="javascript:onDateChange(this);" type="date" class="firstDate" name="firstDate">
            <input onchange="javascript:onDateChange(this);" type="date" class="secondDate" name="secondDate">
        </form>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function formatDate(date) {
  var firstDate = document.getElementsByClassName("firstDate")[0].value;
  var secondDate = document.getElementsByClassName("secondDate")[0].value;
  if (firstDate && secondDate) {
    d1 = new Date(firstDate);
    d2 = new Date(secondDate);
    var tmp = d1 - d2;
    if (tmp > 86400000) {
      document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "<=====";
    } else {
      document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = " =====>";
    };
  }
}
```

```css
#output {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-inner">
  <form>
    <input type="date" class="firstDate" name="firstDate" onchange="formatDate(this.value);">
    <input type="date" class="secondDate" name="secondDate" onchange="formatDate(this.value);">
  </form>
</div>
<span id="output"></span>
```